# Latest stable version of Elastic Search for Spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic search. We are building a Spring boot application with Elastic search.

Currently, we are bound to use `Spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE`.

1. Which latest version of Elastic search is most stable to use with
       `Spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE`?
2. Is using the
       `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` dependency best option to integrate with the Elastic search?
3. What if we upgrade the spring boot version or downgrade the ES version in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories) url points to official documentation of Spring and please find snippet of documentation, for your convenience, below.

[image]

I would recommend careful validation when selecting the version of Elasticsearch and/or the version of the High Level Rest Client (when you would decide to use this library). We've been using the old 6.0 version of the High Level Rest Client in the past and have been forced to upgrade to version 7.4 because of performance.

But, since you indicated, you plan to use **spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch**, it's possible you won't use the High Level Rest Client.